# How should I Encode my Twitter Key?

Tags: java, android, twitter

I have my consumer and secret key. I know I have to encode the secret key when it is included in my app. What is the best way to go around doing this?

Comment: the OAUTH library you would have to use should handle all of this.  ive only done this on ios so im sure it a little different for android, but either way, where are you storing it that it needs encryption?  in code? in a database? or are you worried about when you send it to twitter?

Comment: I am worried about when I store it in my app. Because I keep reading that I should  have it encoded within the app

Comment: i could be wrong.  But when i did OAUTH for ios there was nothing that told me this, and i did nothing then use the library for it.  im not a hacker so idk, but from what i do know there is no way to uncompile an apk to extract text like that from it.  now sending the key to twitter shouldnt be plain text but once again the OAUTH library should handle that.   i guess wait and see what others have to say.

Comment: @owengerig I think you are wrong, even Android and IOS apps are able to decompiled using the right tools, and that isn't a good idea to mantain your keys "in clear"

Answer (score 0):

The first solution could be to use obfuscation (search for `ProGuard` for Android, there are a lot of resources about it) and the next one could be to add extra security decoding all of your strings using one way encryption (algorithms like `AES` does are useful).

Of course the best option is to avoid adding this kind of keys and moving to the server side, adding the code to be used in the Android client. This solution not always can be applied, of course, but did you asked yourself if it's really needed the key in your client device? If you move your Twitter key to a server that does all the job related with the Twitter service (publish, get the timeline, etc), you won't need to add it to the app, you only will need to communicate securely your clients with your server. I know, that this solution only could apply if you have a really powerful service (lot of effort to do it) and you are able to sign to your server with secure methods (SSL, etc).

Comment: thank you for your reply. Could you please explain the last option a little more as I have not come across that method before.

Comment: i dont get how you would do this.  let say u stored it in a sql database.  even if u encrypt it prior to going into the database the plain text key is still in the code.  im no guru by a long shot but how would u do any encryption on the key without touching the plain text version of the key within your code?

Comment: o maybe i can conceive it but there would have to be a third party retainer/retriever of that data.